# ¿Bug al llamar a OnCompletionListener de MediaPlayer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**Contexto:** Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de reproducción de música a modo de aprendizaje. He creado un adaptador personalizado que carga una lista de canciones en un *ListView*, este adaptador tiene 3 botones *(play, pause y reset)*. Haciendo debugg y testing comprobé que si el usuario empieza a pulsar el botón de play de diferentes canciones aveces se llama al método *OnCompletionListener*.

Como está sin refactorizar y la clase es extensa pongo el Listener en cuestión:

```
        //Al completarse la canción
    mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener (new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener (){
        @Override
        public void onCompletion (MediaPlayer mp) {
            botonEnable (botonAnteriorPlay);
            botonDissable (botonAnteriorPause);
            Toast.makeText (contexto,"onCompletion",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
            //Reestablezco la posición a 0 cuando se ha completado la canción
            for(HashMap.Entry<Integer,Integer> i : cancionesEnMarcha.entrySet ()){
                if(idCancion == i.getKey ()){
                    mediaplayer.seekTo (0);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Básicamente estoy guardando el estado de las canciones en un *HashMap* y al completarse le hago un *seekTo a 0* para que al pulsar de nuevo a play se reproduzca desde el inicio. Esta *HashMap* guarda el estado de las canciones para que se pueda reproducir por donde estaba el usuario escuchando.

Debido a mi falta de experiencia no se por que se produce este "bug" (que seguro que no es un bug y es que hago algo mal).

Y tengo dos dudas al respecto:

**¿Por que se llama al listener si la canción no ha terminado?**

Me he apoyado en la documentación oficial de android sobre la clase MediaPlayer.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando ocurre un error en el MediaPlayer y no tenes seteado el `OnErrorListener` te llama al `OnCompletionListener`.

Agrégale el `OnErrorListener` y fijate bien que error esta tirando, seguramente tiene problemas al iniciarse varios `MediaPlayers` al mismo tiempo.

En ese caso deberías detener uno cuando le das play al otro para que esto no te pase.

Comment: Pues toda la razón del mundo, me saltaba el error -38, indagaré por que pero parece ser que me falta algún prepare del media player o algún stop. Ahora bien, puse el Listener onErrorListener, devolviendo true y sigue saltando onCompletionListener a pesar de devolver true, entiendo que hasta que se subsane el error seguirá saltando. ¿No? 
Perdón por mi ignorancia, aún me queda mucho por estudiar.

Comment: Muy bien, el error 38 segun la documentacion es "Notification that new meadi stream has been started", o sea que le diste play a otro media player sin que termine el que estaba ejecutando. Asegurate de poner en pausa o detener todos los media player antes de darle start a otro.

Comment: Sí, justo lo leí por internet, no lo encontré en la documentación, estaba leyendo la sección de MediaPlayer (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) y no vi ninguna referencia. ¿Dónde se miran estos errores? Soy demasiado nuevo. 

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, no encontré aún dónde está el fallo por que se supone que llamo a stop() - reset() cargo con setDataSorce() - prepare() y start(), entre otras cosas. Pero seguro que daré con la clave, marco tu respuesta como correcta ya que la pregunta fue más que resuelta.  Gracias.